# SQLite.net exception on screen rotation on android 4.1+

Tags: xamarin.android

I am currently working on a cross-platform application using Monodroid/Xamarin. It uses a SQLite.net database and at the moment I have only built the Android UI.

In the application there is a long running method on a background thread which does several database reads and writes.

I was testing this long running method on a Nexus 7 running android 4.2.2 and it seems as though after a second screen rotation, a SQLite exception is thrown and the application crashes.

The exception stack trace varies depending on when you rotate the screen but the exception is always object not set to an instance inside Prepare2.

The interesting part is when testing on Samsung Galaxy S2 running 4.1.2 an exception still occurs but it is a different exception.
Furthermore, testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 and emulators the error is not thrown at all and the method completes just fine.

Any ideas, hints, suggestions would be much appreciated.

As a side question  - in all the cross platform applications i have seen using Xamarin - the database layer and or repository is always static - whats the reason for this?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to identify the problem from what you've written - would be easier if you'd included some code about how you are accessing the database from your app.

However, I **suspect** that the problem here will be due to some interaction between the lifecycle of your UI `Activity` and the way it interacts with the SQLite database.

By default, when you rotate an `Activity`, then the existing instance is destroyed and a new one is created - your old Activity will be called to store its state in `SaveInstanceState` and your new rotated Activity will get called with a bundle in `OnCreate`.

This is why the database layer is often static/singleton in the samples - it's an easy way to allow the same database instance to be shared by multiple Activities/Components.

I **guess** that your Activity is doing something with the database during `OnCreate` - and that this is being called after each rotation/creation? Alternatively maybe your long-running method is trying to do something after the Activity that's hosting it has been finished and disposed?

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for your response. Unfortunately it is not possible to post any code in this case. I am aware of how the rotation works with the activities and I am fairly certain there isnt anything in the OnCreate that would cause this. If there was, wouldnt the error show in all three versions of Android I have tested on?? Whereas currently its only on Jelly Bean and higher?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this turned out to be a issue with mulithreading and Linq not playing well together. Thanks to Stuart for his answer.